Session cookie undefined in server after client request
I have a little microservices app with 3 services: Client (Next.js), Auth (Node.js) and Posts (Node.js). For authentication, I am signing a JWT token and storing that in a session cookie using express-session. I can successfully generate tokens and store in the browser using the Auth service but when I try to make a request to the Posts service using Fetch API in Next.js (credentials: "include"is added) the cookies are undefined in Posts service. The session configurations are identical in all services with same secrets. Any ideas why this is happening? I believe it's because the Posts service is considered a different origin but I don't know how to allow it. Your help is appreciated. Thank you!
Server boilerplate
const app = express();
app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.use(
    session({
        secret: "yourSecretKey",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            secure: false,
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        },
    })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/", routes);
app.use(errorHandler);

export { app };

Sign in route:
const signIn = catchError(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const user = res.locals.user!;
    const { authMethod } = req.params;
    if (authMethod && authMethod != AuthMethodsEnum.SIGNIN) {
        return next();
    }
    req.session.authToken = await JWT.sign({
        id: user.id,
        email: user.email,
        exp: Date.now() + Number.parseInt(process.env.AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRATION!),
    });

    res.statusCode = 200;
    return res.json({});
});

Client request:
fetch(url, {
        method,
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
        },
    })
        .then(async (response) => {
            const res = await response.json();
            console.log(res);
            if (response.ok) {
                onSuccess(res);
            } else {
                throw { response: res, status: response.status };
            }
        });

Posts service middleware:
export const requireAuth = catchError(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (!req.session.authToken) {
        console.log("No session token!");
        throw new AuthenticationError();
    }
    JWT.verify(req.session.authToken)
        .then(async (decoded) => {
            req.currentUser = decoded;
            next();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (err instanceof CustomError) {
                return next(err);
            }
            if (err instanceof TokenExpiredError) {
                throw new AuthenticationError("Session expired. Please sign in.");
            }
            throw new AuthenticationError("Authentication failed. Please sign in.");
        });
});


Cookies are per-origin. It's possible to set a subdomain cookie (if the origins share part of the domain), but you're probably better off trying something else. Like an Authorization header and proper OAuth2 flows. But if you want to ignore all that and use reliable cookies, you're best off putting everything under the same origin.
